# Wordpress Installation for multi-domains with nginx and php-fpm

Tags: multisite, installation, nginx

I am new to Wordpress. I googled around but could not find precise steps to install Wordpress with nginx multi-site configuration.

I want to install wordpress 3.3.1 on Ubuntu 11.10. I already installed

- php5-fpm
- nginx
- mysql

I have two domains that I want use same wordpress installation

```
domain1.com 
domain2.com
```

Could you provide nginx and wordpress configuration for multi domain setup?
Thanks for all.

Answer (score 3):

You should look in [Wordpress Codex page](https://wordpress.org/support/article/nginx/) related to Nginx. It's best manual for configuring nginx for wordpress I've seen over the internet.